# How to create PDF in Swift

Tags: html, uiwebview, swift2

I want to create a PDF using `UIWebView`. As I have any work sheet details and I want to save generate PDF in Swift. I'm using HTML format with tables but in second page my border is cutting.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For Swift 2 I used  to use 
html string (is the exact html code used for your table) as String! 
Then

```
    let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
    let fmt = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: html)

    render.addPrintFormatter(fmt, startingAtPageAtIndex: 0)

    // 3. Assign paperRect and printableRect

    let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 612, height: 792) // some defaults
    let printable = page.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)

    render.setValue(NSValue(CGRect: page), forKey: "paperRect")
    render.setValue(NSValue(CGRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")

    // 4. Create PDF context and draw
    //let pointzero = CGPoint(x: 0,y :0)
    let rect = CGRect.zero
    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, .zero, nil)

    for i in 0..<render.numberOfPages {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        render.drawPageAtIndex( i, inRect: UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds())
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // 5. Save PDF file
   let path = "\(NSTemporaryDirectory())sd.pdf"

    pdfData.writeToFile( path, atomically: true)
    print("open \(path)")
```